# GWT: Help trying to format a composite widget. Tried CSS stuff and it has no effect

Tags: css, gwt

Consider the following widget:

```
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Composite;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Label;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.ListBox;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.TextBox;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HasHorizontalAlignment;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HasVerticalAlignment;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.FlexTable;

public class SelectorPanel extends Composite
{
    private final FlexTable flexTable = new FlexTable();
    private final Label lbltitle = new Label("##Title");
    private final ListBox listBox = new ListBox();
    private final Label lblsearchtext = new Label( "##SearchText" );
    private final TextBox tbSearch = new TextBox();

    public SelectorPanel()
    {
        listBox.setVisibleItemCount( 10 );
        flexTable.setStyleName("SearchPanel");
        flexTable.setBorderWidth(0);

        initWidget( flexTable );
        flexTable.setSize("200px", "0px");
        lbltitle.setWordWrap( false );

        flexTable.setWidget( 0, 0, lbltitle );

        flexTable.setWidget( 1, 0, listBox );
        listBox.setWidth("100%");

        flexTable.setWidget( 2, 0, lblsearchtext );
        tbSearch.setMaxLength( 32 );

        flexTable.setWidget( 3, 0, tbSearch );
        flexTable.getCellFormatter().setHorizontalAlignment( 0, 0, HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_LEFT );
        flexTable.getCellFormatter().setVerticalAlignment( 2, 0, HasVerticalAlignment.ALIGN_MIDDLE );
        flexTable.getCellFormatter().setVerticalAlignment( 1, 0, HasVerticalAlignment.ALIGN_MIDDLE );
        flexTable.getCellFormatter().setVerticalAlignment( 3, 0, HasVerticalAlignment.ALIGN_MIDDLE );
        flexTable.getCellFormatter().setVerticalAlignment(0, 0, HasVerticalAlignment.ALIGN_BOTTOM);
        flexTable.getCellFormatter().setHorizontalAlignment(3, 0, HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_CENTER);
    }

}
```

I have tried messing with CSS spacing and padding (and I have no idea what the difference is) and it has no effect.  I can even change colors in the CSS tool and that too has no effect.

Anyway, here are the problems with widget:

1. The title text "##Title" is cut off by the list box below it.  I would like some spacing or padding below it so that doesn't happen.
2. The ##SearchText label is too close to the listbox above it and also overlapped by the text box below it.
3. Finally the whole thing appears at the extreme left on my browser and I would like a little spacing between it and the edge of the screen.

I can 'kind of' format this by adjusting cell sizes and what not.  I can't get it right, only better. I am also thinking this must be the wrong way to go about it.

When I look at the stockwatcher application they use CSS to do things like this, but I can't get anything to happen.  The following is my CSS file and the two items are just experimental and have no effect on anything.

```
Boxed {
    margin-top: auto;
    border: thin solid;
    background-color: Silver;
}
#test {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Is there anyone who can explain this to me?  I just do not understand why CSS has no effect or how to resolve the above problems.  I can apply the above CSS to the cells or to the labels or other UI objects and nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all i can't see your overlapping issues. See the picture. This looks good to me:

[image]

To the CSS-questions: You need to reference the Class-Name or the ID of you component. A class is referenced by ".className", an id by "#id".

If you want to move your widget to the left by 100 pixels you can use this CSS:

```
.SearchPanel{ margin-left:100px; }
```

Or you can even center it with:

```
.SearchPanel{ margin:auto; }
```

You applied the css-class "SearchPanel" in your code with:

```
flexTable.setStyleName("SearchPanel");
```

This way you can apply classes to every component.

If you wan't more spacing on the top and the bottom of your label (##Title and ##SearchText) you could add some margin as well:

```
.gwt-Label { 
   margin-top: 10px;
   margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I think the problem has been my names of my CSS elements.  I am not familiar with CSS and just picked those names from other examples I saw.  If I just put a . in front of my names, suddenly all my css stuff started to work.  I had read several CSS tutorials and one of them said anything about how to name stuff in css.